# How to reference self in a definition?

Tags: swagger

```
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: Simple API
paths:
  /:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
definitions:
  Thing:
    properties:
      parent_thing:
        allOf:
          - $ref: '#/definitions/Thing'
        description: parent of this thing
```

Here is the minimal example. If I write this in swagger-editor, it shows that parent_thing is of type `undefined`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqta3.png

How do I fix that? I want `Thing` to have a reference to other `Thing`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have self-references, but you probably don't use the `allOf` construct:

```
definitions:
  Thing:
    properties:
      parent_thing:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Thing'
```

The above is valid, if the swagger-editor is not showing it correctly, that is a bug.

Comment: Both ways show "undefined". Btw, do you think it's wrong to use allOf? I used it because I want to use custom description which tells what the property means.

Comment: Please file a ticket in swagger-editor.  What is listed above is correct and valid, if it does not display, it needs to be fixed.

Comment: It seems it's still not fixed; are you sure it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by a proxy model (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047433/1046909):

```
    ...
    _MessageProxy:
      description: Message
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - user
        - body
        - publishedAt
      properties:
        id:
          title: Message id
          type: string
          readOnly: true
          example: '595f4acf828b0b766ad11290'
        user:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
    Message:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/_MessageProxy'
        - type: object
          properties:
            parent:
              title: Parent
              readOnly: true
              allOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/_MessageProxy'
    ...
```