# Refer to self in OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have a data model definition in OpenAPI 3.0, using SwaggerHub to display the UI. I want one of the properties of a model to be `related`, which is an array of properties of the same model.

```yaml
    Foo:
      properties:
        title:
          type: string
        related:
          type: array
          items: 
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
```

The parser doesn't seem to like this - the UI shows the `related` property as an empty array. Is this kind of self-reference possible in OpenAPI 3.0?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Object array rendered as empty array in Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44871128/113116)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your definition is correct, it's just Swagger UI currently does not render circular-referenced definitions properly. See [issue #3325](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3325) for details.

What you can do is add a model `example`, and Swagger UI will display this example instead of trying to generate an example from the definition.

```yaml
    Foo:
      type: object
      properties:
        title:
          type: string
        related:
          type: array
          items: 
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
      example:     # <-------
        title: foo
        related:
          - title: bar
          - title: baz
            related:
              - title: qux
```

Alternatively, you can add an `example` just for the `related` array:

```yaml
    Foo:
      type: object
      properties:
        title:
          type: string
        related:
          type: array
          items: 
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
          example:   # <--- Make sure "example" is on the same level as "type: array"
            - title: bar
            - title: baz
              related:
                - title: qux
```

Answer (score 1):

I got tired of this pesky situation, so I went with no example at all and chose to get rid of the items property, add a description element and use an empty array instead:

```
Foo:
  type: object
  properties:
    title:
      type: string
    related:
      type: array
      description: Array of Foo elements
      example: []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by a proxy model:

```
    ...
    _MessageProxy:
      description: Message
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - user
        - body
        - publishedAt
      properties:
        id:
          title: Message id
          type: string
          readOnly: true
          example: '595f4acf828b0b766ad11290'
        user:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
    Message:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/_MessageProxy'
        - type: object
          properties:
            parent:
              title: Parent
              readOnly: true
              allOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/_MessageProxy'
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dummy model and cross reference:

```
Foo:
      properties:
        title:
          type: string
        related:
          type: array
          items: 
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/_Foo'

_Foo:
      properties:
        title:
          type: string
        related:
          type: array
          items: 
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
```